# I am trying to prevent someone being able to fill in a text input if the previous drop down menu hasnt been selected

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

My task is to make a form with drop down menu for title, text input for first name, last name and email and then intrests as checkboxes.
i have succesfully made the form and have put in place messages when something isnt right on the form however now i need stop somone from being able to type in the first name if they havent selected a title or if title === --

i then need to do the same for the last name but with first name rather than title, i should be able to work round that if i know how to do the first one as the only change is the input type.

if anyone could help thatd be great :)

Comment: can you host the code in glitch or codesandbox or stackblitz  , show us what you did ?     https://codesandbox.io/    https://stackblitz.com/  https://glitch.com/

Comment: i could make it a respitory on github if youd like ?

Comment: or i can have a quick look and see on the ones you have provided

Comment: @דולבדובלון  https://github.com/joshua-mcfield99/infoForm#infoform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verry simple example.

By default, the fields are set to "disabled". The script checks for the previous field in the list and if it has content removes the "disabled" from the next field

```js
var list = document.getElementsByClassName('inpt');

for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i].addEventListener("change", function () {
        if (this.value.length > 0) {
            checkInputs(this);
        }
    });
}

function checkInputs(x) {
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length-1; i++) {
        if (list[i].id === x.id) {
            var z = document.getElementById(list[i + 1].id)
            z.removeAttribute('disabled');
            z.focus();
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<select class="inpt" id="first">
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
    <option value="three">three</option>
</select>

<input class="inpt" id="name" type="text" disabled>
<input class="inpt" id="surname" type="text" disabled>
<input class="inpt" id="age" type="text" disabled>
```

Comment: Better: `checkInputs` should also disable the inputs again if the user removes the characters.

Comment: Yes you are right! Just make a quick example. I hope the OP will use it as a basis and make the necessary changes

Comment: would i use the last section again but with - instead of the +? @54k

Comment: I added a drop-down input to the example :)